# How to download debug symbol for a specific version

Tags: debugging, version, symbols, pdb-files

I known I can use, the tool "symchk" to download PDB files. But when I do so, I have to provide the dll. It will download only the pdb associated to a specific dll provided.

> symchk.exe /r /v C:\Dev\Symbols\mydll.dll /s
>   SRV*C:\Dev\Symbols\PDB*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Is it possible to download the debug symbol from a specific version without providing the dll ? For example, I would like to download the PDB file for mydll.dll with this specific 6.1.7601.17940.

Thanks in advance for your time.